# Pass a parameter to a ViewModel and show its data

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have created an application which uses WPF and MVVM following [this article from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72724/Beginning-a-WPF-MVVM-application-Navigating-betwee).

I have a view, `TVSeriesView`, which has a `TVSeriesViewModel`. These two are connected using a DataTemplate which is done following the article.

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Implementation:TVSeriesViewModel}">
    <TVSeriesLibrary:TVSeriesView />
</DataTemplate>
```

The idea is to pass my model, the `TVSeries`, to this ViewModel as I have a property named `TVSeries` in the ViewModel. When this property is set, I will populate other properties such as `Title`, `Cover` and so on. These properties are meant to be binded to controls in the view.

```
public class TVSeriesViewModel : ViewModelBase, ITVSeriesViewModel
{
    private TVSeries _tvSeries;
    private string _title;
    private ImageSource _cover;

    public TVSeries TVSeries
    {
        get
        {
            return this._tvSeries;
        }
        set
        {
            this._tvSeries = value;
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this._title;
        }
        set
        {
            this._title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public ImageSource Cover
    {
        get
        {
            return this._cover;
        }
        set
        {
            this._cover = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Cover");
        }
    }
}
```

First and foremost, does this sound like the right way to do it?

Next, does anyone know how to pass a parameter (a `TVSeries` object) to the ViewModel when the `TVSeriesView` is shown?

And lastly, does anyone know how I can directly access resources in the view? For example if I don't want to use data binding but instead want to set the image directly like this:

`myImage.ImageSource = myImageSource`

Comment: why creating a viewmodel when you dont want to use binding?

Comment: You're right. I believe I will use databinding. I just thought it sometimes might be easier to just access a control directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View and ViewModel together are one of the possible representations of the Model.

You can pass a repository handle which would be eventually responsible for data access or 
Concrete/abstract object of Model through Dependency Injection via Constructor or
Dependency Injection, via property/method or 
In more crude way you can write a DB access code in your VM (obviously it's not suggested.)

I would prefer as the order given here. Your code is doing the third option.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can I ask you to give an example?